# How to find and cancel background Thread in Swift

Tags: swift

I am calling a monitoring task via thread using the following code which is called from the `viewDidLoad()` in a `ViewController`:

```swift
let myDaemon = Thread(target: self.myMonitor, selector:#selector(self.myMonitor), object: nil)
myDaemon.start()
```

I have been unable to find a way to find and cancel that thread without closing the app. Is there maybe an alternate way to launch the thread so I can cancel it if needed?

I thought about creating an observer so I could cancel it from another VC but since the Daemon is initialized in the `viewDidLoad`, I can't access it outside of that block.

I'm using Swift 5. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Keep a reference to that `instance`, and then call `cancel()` on it?

Comment: And, of course, any code running on that thread would need to check the `isCancelled` value and exit, if so.

Comment: As @Rob pointed out, cancel() doesn't necessarily cancel the thread unless the process checks for it which I don't believe it does.

Comment: If you give us more information what this “monitoring task” is, we can advise regarding better patterns than a `Thread`. That's almost invariably the wrong solution, but we can’t advise further without more information. Also, you probably want to provide more info regarding what platform you are on, too, as macOS might need different solutions than iOS or the like.

Comment: @Rob This is for a macOS project and the monitoring task is listening for inputs from an attached hardware device for button presses. 
The application itself must always be listening for device presses even when not in focus. It works perfectly now however it seems apparent that I need to load that monitoring daemon differently.

Comment: It's not obvious what kind of attached hardware you're describing, but generally this is handled with DriverKit, most often with something like an IOInterruptDispatchSource to send you an interrupt when an event occurs.

Comment: @Rob. I'm using IOHIDManager to monitor for HID button presses and pass home values into my app where I respond accordingly. It's my first time interacting with hardware in swift. Basically I initialize my IOHIDManager and configured my callbacks and then run it in a loop using RunLoop which listens for the button presses. I based my code off of some research I did on interacting with external hardware with swift.

Comment: There's generally no need for a separate thread if you're already using a runloop. The whole point of a runloop is to enable cooperative multitasking without needing threads. You generally can just use the main runloop, unless you're performing CPU-intensive operations or calling blocking APIs. "Listen for lots of separate events efficiently" is what the runloop lives for.

Comment: @Rob. I really appreciate all of your help. I'm in the process of updating my runloop so it can be stopped when needed but am still running it in a thread so I'll change that up as well.

Comment: @Rob. I seem to have a solution that is working. Not being 100% comfortable with my understanding, I'd really appreciate any feedback;
1. Moved the Monitor function to a an external static class
2. When needed, I call a start() method in the class which loads the monitor. I have a class variable called runLoop and I assign the CFRunLoopGetCurrent to is when starting, then call CFRunLoopRun() to start
3. When I need to stop, I call the CFRunLoopStop(self.runLoop) from the main DispatchQueue. (Not sure if I need to call it this way or not)
I can stop and start as needed now. Thoughts?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You typically wouldn't start and stop the main runloop until the program ends (for GUI app, this will tend to either hang the app, or terminate it). If you want to stop monitoring, you would remove the monitor from the runloop, not stop the runloop. And typically you wouldn't need a dispatch queue here, either. You just set it all up on the main runloop when you start. The main runloop doesn't "belong" to this monitor. You just want to attach the monitor to it.

Comment: RunLoops are most often a tool used *instead* of threads and dispatch queues (in the days before GCD, there were reasons to make your own RunLoops on secondary threads, but this is quite uncommon now). You shouldn't need to make one, or pass it around. You almost certainly just want to use the main one. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html

Comment: @RobNapier My reasoning for ending the RunLoop is that there are times when I never want the loop to run as I don't need to listen for hardware events. Its actually rare that I would need to switch back and forth between listening for events but I need the ability to do so as there will be some clients switching back and forth. I have removed stopping the RunLoop from the DispatchQueue as well. It seems to be working as needed. I will look into removing the monitor from the loop as well.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should almost never use Thread in Swift. Directly accessing threads [has been discouraged](https://developers.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) in Cocoa since longer than Swift has been a language. You should generally be using, in order of preference for the kinds of problems threads are usually used for, async/await (possibly plus an AsyncChannel), OperationQueues, or DispatchQueues. That said, it's a fine question, and there are still very rare cases where a Thread would be appropriate, or at least useful.

To cancel a thread, you will either need to keep track of it (the returned value) so you can call `.cancel()`, or you need to have a way to communicate with the thread (a Pipe for example) so that you can send a custom "stop" message. That means storing that returned value (or the communication mechanism) somewhere outside the VC.

A ViewController should not own a global object like a Thread. ViewControllers come and go. You should move your thread management (if you're going to do thread management, which you generally shouldn't) into a model object that the VCs share.

Note that canceling a thread does not cause a thread to stop running. The *only* thing it does is set the `isCancelled` flag. If is still up to your thread to periodically check itself for cancellation and stop. (You may already know this, but it's a very common confusion, so I want to make sure anyone reading this later is aware.)

There is no list of all existing threads for you to search (and that would be pretty obnoxious since the frameworks generate quite a lot of threads you would need to crawl through). If you want to keep track of a thread, you need to store it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I had looked into using a DispatchQueue but haven't looked at Operation Queue so I will check into that.
I do have a BaseVC that I use for common loading and closing functions for all of my VCs so I will look into using a DispatchQueue or OperationQueue. I can't really wrap my head around how I could do this with an Async operation but will look into it as well.

Comment: The BaseVC is still a VC. VCs should not own services or models. They should be separate and passed into the VCs (or, more simply, use a `.shared` static instance, which is a very common and useful approach).